# TYPO3 menu based on couple of lists of ids

Tags: menu, typo3, typoscript

Is it possible to build menu in TypoScript which is based on couple of list of `id's` for example:

List one:

```
20 = HMENU
20.special = list
20.special.value = 35, 56, 51, 43, 22
```

List two

```
30 = HMENU
30.special = list
30.special.value = 43, 1, 25, 98
```

etc..

I need to insert in the footer section a six column menu with different links to different site. Any ideas how to do that in one menu?

Answer (score 2):

What about using `directory` menu ?

1. Create a folder in which you put all the pages you want in your menu.
   [image]
2. Create a constant with the `id` of the folder.
3. Then create a menu like this one:

   ```
   # Links list
   20 = HMENU
   20 {

     special = directory
     special.value = {$constants.page.footer.links}

     1 = TMENU
     1 {
       noBlur = 1

       NO {
         wrapItemAndSub = <li>|</li>
         ATagTitle.field = subtitle // title
       }

       ACT = 1
       ACT {
         wrapItemAndSub = <li class="active">|</li>
         ATagTitle.field = subtitle // title
       }

       CUR = 1
       CUR {
         wrapItemAndSub = <li class="active">|</li>
         ATagTitle.field = subtitle // title
       }
     }
   }
   ```